# Is any gallery plugin available to generate galleries from existing uploaded images?

Tags: plugins, gallery

I have tried [NextGEN Gallery](http://alexrabe.de/wordpress-plugins/nextgen-gallery/) and [Lazyest Gallery](http://brimosoft.nl/lazyest/gallery/), but both seem to require to upload it with their form. [PhotoSmash](http://smashly.net/blog/farewell-to-photosmash/) is not supported any longer.

Could you please tell me which plugin (that is supported and works with the latest WordPress) can generate galleries with already uploaded photos?

Answer (score 1):

Lazyest Gallery does not require to upload using the admin form.
In fact, the plugin is built to automatically index your existing uploaded images.
Just enter your images folder in the lazyest gallery settings and the plugin will build a gallery.

(I am the author of Lazyest Gallery)

Comment: Please disclose/mention your affiliation when talking about your own (or otherwise connected) code.

Comment: @macbrink: Please tell me how I should put my existing images in one gallery without uploading them again. I can access three Lazyest Gallery pages, one of them is the themes page. Here are screenshots of the two others: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/EWi7wi0yq5GMCkRrW6eOcXHGVntSY16OnUs3_WSIxGY and https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/nGX4t0roXoiqiWw1d7h29XHGVntSY16OnUs3_WSIxGY